# Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available

Tags: fonts, warnings, size

when I add another slide on my presentation, I get warning about this one

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{french}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

%\usepackage{msg-msg}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usepackage{textpos}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}

\definecolor{asparagus}{rgb}{0.53, 0.66, 0.42}
\usecolortheme[named=asparagus]{structure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\title{\textbf {Theoretical Study of Electrical Conductivity in Graphene-Like Materials}}
\author{Latifah Salem Alrobiei \texorpdfstring{ \\ [1cm]{\small Supervised by \\ Dr.Narjes A. Ben Brabim \hspace{35pt} Dr. Abdullah A. Shaltout} \\ {\small Assistant Prof. of Solid state \qquad Associate Prof. of Atomic and} \\ {physics \hfill \hspace{35pt} \qquad Molecular Spectra}}{}}


\institute[Taif University] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Department of Physics \\
  Taif University 
  }

\date{1442-2020}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{university-logo}{TU}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{university-logo}{TU}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Graphene}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
            \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{graphenee.png}
            \caption{Graphene crystal structure}
            \end{figure}\pause
            \end{center}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item In $2004$ Geim and Novoselov work experimentally to isolate a single atomic layer of carbon (graphene)for the first time by using 'Scotch tape' to award with the Nobel Prize in Physics in $2010$.\pause
                \item Graphene exhibit very interesting properties, such as \pause
                    \begin{normalsize}
                        \item Linear energy dispersion.\pause
                        \item Carriers with zero mass.\pause
                        \item High mobility rather than the best metal.      
                    \end{normalsize}     
            \end{itemize}
       \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end {document}
```

the warning say
Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available

how to avoid that please?

the Log File as below

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sc' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 87.
[4
<./graphenee.png>]
File: graphenee.png Graphic file (type png)
<use graphenee.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: graphenee.png used on input line 87.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 101.78102pt x 83.11113pt.
[5
]
File: graphenee.png Graphic file (type png)
<use graphenee.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: graphenee.png used on input line 87.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 101.78102pt x 83.11113pt.
[6
]
File: graphenee.png Graphic file (type png)
<use graphenee.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: graphenee.png used on input line 87.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 101.78102pt x 83.11113pt.
[7
]
File: graphenee.png Graphic file (type png)
<use graphenee.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: graphenee.png used on input line 87.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 101.78102pt x 83.11113pt.
[8
]
File: graphenee.png Graphic file (type png)
<use graphenee.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: graphenee.png used on input line 87.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 101.78102pt x 83.11113pt.
[9
]
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./groupIV.png): libpng: internal error
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal example such that others can test your code as is. Here there is no document class (I presume it is beamer) and no preamble. Additionally, we don't have your images (they are irrelevant and can be removed).

Comment: Back to the warning: Something in your code want to be typeset in small caps sans serif. Hardly any font setup provides this combination so LaTeX will choose something else and issues this warning.

Comment: I add the complement

Comment: regarding to your explaining about the warning, how to fix that? are there any package I can use to avoid warning?

Comment: You cannot do much here other than ignore it. Which language is this suppose to be on? The problem comes from the `french` setup for `babel` as it wants to typeset the figure name in the caption as small caps (IMO rather annoying feature for the french setup)

Comment: in my documents I never use the French language, I wrote every thinks by English, when I try to cancel the lines %\usepackage{french}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}, I get error line1: ! Package babel Error: Unknown language `french'. Either you have

Comment: That's because `babel` writes the language to the aux file, since you now removed fremch it does not know french anymore. Just delere the aux file. Since your doc is in english would just have used `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}` (the last language is the active one), compile once, now the language in the aux is `english` and `french` can be safely removed. This is a know issue with `babel`

Comment: I get warning: Package french.ldf Warning: OT1 encoding should not be used for French.
(french.ldf) Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble
(french.ldf) of your document; reported on input line 38.
(thesis.nav)
  I don't know how to ignore that

Comment: Delete the `nav` file as well, the language has probably been written to that as well. If you are using `pdflatex` it is a good idea to always use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or similar anyways. Especially for languages other than english.

Comment: I add the line \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, there was no error but also I get not any output, please let me know how to delete the nav file? Thank you

Comment: I read about arara tool but I don't know how to set up in the preamble in my beamer

Comment: That is a different question

Comment: It is your PC, thus you should now how to delete a file. Note in windows, has a tendency to hide the file extensions.

Comment: if it is not useful in my case, I back off the question

Comment: please I need your help I rewrite the framesby using just those packages  ```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\definecolor{asparagus}{rgb}{0.53, 0.66, 0.42}
\usecolortheme[named=asparagus]{structure}
\usepackage{xcolor}

``` I don't get for second-time error, warning or output? Is there any other way to solve the problem other then delete the files from MikTex? Thank you

Comment: I mean without delete the files from MikTe

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not your personal support, what yo are asking right now does not seem to be related to your question, so please post a new question.

Comment: It is the same documents I try doing changes in the preamble, as explained in the comment above. I found that there was no warning or error and also no output